# How can I rewrite a URL with a MIME type attached?

Tags: iis, web, web-config, config

I got an URL like http://mydomain.com/something/externalDocs/text.doc

And i want this to be ridirected do another URL. Like http://mydomain.com/something/download/online/text.doc. Then the Browser should ask me how I would like to open the file. And this for any filetype in this Directory. Like .doc and .pdf.

What I got so Far...

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="DownloadRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(?:/externalDocs/)(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="(?:/download/online/){R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

How could i add something like...

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
```

...into that exact rule above.

Thank you for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just add a new mime type mapping in your web.config as below?

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".doc" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".doc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```